# parameters of histogram with R

Tags: r, plot, histogram, data-science, axis

First, I wanted to be able to display the absciss axis with decimal numbers (example: 1.5, 2.6, ...), but the problem is that when I display the histogram with my code, then automatically the x-axis displays whole number as you can see in the follow picture (I have circled in red what I would like to change): [hist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpo2I.jpg)
How can i change the parameters to be able to get these whole numbers into decimals?

Secondly, I would like the numbers that appear on the x-axis to correspond exactly to my breaks vector.

Could someone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
my_data <- transform(my_data, new = as.numeric(new/1000000))
sal_hist_default = hist(my_data$new, breaks = c(1,6.3,11.6,16.9,22.2,27.5), col = "blue", border = "black", las = 1, include.lowest=TRUE,right=FALSE, main="Salary Of best category", xlab = "salaries", ylab = "num of players",xlim = c(1,27.5), ylim = c(0,600))
```

Comment: Could you share the part of the code where you plot the histogram?

Comment: i added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really provide sample data, but try this:

```
set.seed(42)
new <- rnorm(1000, 14, 3.5)
my_data <- data.frame(new)
sal_hist_default = hist(my_data$new, breaks = c(1, 6.3, 11.6, 16.9, 22.2, 27.5), col = "blue",
      border = "black", las = 1, include.lowest=TRUE,right=FALSE, main="Salary Of best category",
      xlab = "salaries", ylab = "num of players",xlim = c(1,27.5), ylim = c(0,600), xaxt="n")
axis(1, c(1, 6.3, 11.6, 16.9, 22.2, 27.5), c(1, 6.3, 11.6, 16.9, 22.2, 27.5))
```

[image: Histogram]